# How to use MediaElement.SetPlaybackSource

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

Can any one help me understand how to use the UWP MediaElement.SetPlaybackSource?

I went through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.setplaybacksource.aspx) link, however unable to figure-out/understand the usage of this method. Nor any example provided on MSDN or else where on the web. Thanks!

Comment: Any one knows the answer? Any one from Microsoft? At least the creators of this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [sample code from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback-with-mediasource):

```
//Create a new picker
var filePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();

//Add filetype filters.  In this case wmv and mp4.
filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mkv");

//Set picker start location to the video library
filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;

//Retrieve file from picker
StorageFile file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

if (file != null)
{
    mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
    mediaElement.SetPlaybackSource(mediaSource);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am looking for, with one addition. If I need to write my own IMediaPlaybackSource implementation how can I do that and set as media source.

Comment: You should start with the [MediaSource class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.core.mediasource.aspx). It has a bunch of methods to create a media source from various sources. Then you may use MediaPlaybackItem class to wrap media source into media playback item. I see no methods on how to directly create IMediaPlaybackSource implementation, this interface does not (publically) expose any properties or methods, it is more like a reference to some internal implementation of Media Framework in Windows, available in UWP thru COM-interfaces.